# Python: Joining tuples with backslash

Tags: python, join, tuples, backslash

I'm attempting to join a tuple of two strings using the .join method as follows.

```
>>> my_tuple = ("parent", "child")
>>> "\\".join(my_tuple)
```

I would expect this to return `parent\child`, however, it returns `parent\\child`.

Why is this? Escaping the backslash with another backslash works fine if I attempt to simply print it.

```
>>> print "parent\\child"
>>> parent\child
```

Observed in Python 2.7.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: [str vs. repr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) -- the first is using the `repr` of the string, which always includes escapes for unambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got that right, it's only printing a double backslash because you are not printing it:

```
>>> '\\'.join(my_tuple)
'parent\\child'
>>> print '\\'.join(my_tuple)
parent\child
```

it's the same difference than `__str__` and `__repr__`:

```
>>> '\\'.__repr__()
"'\\\\'"
>>> '\\'.__str__()
'\\'
```

Comment: So the escaping only occurs when printed, and not whilst it's stored in a variable or similar? Interesting, thanks!

Comment: The stored value is the same, but the representation of one backslash is `\\\`.

Comment: @Evidex compare `'\n'` and `print '\n'` for instance.